# How can I avoid using global in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

We're creating a small text-based bank application using python2, and we have to use the user's money for many of the functions. For instance: I create a variable `a = 100` and I used the variable in the function with `global a`. But my teacher doesn't allow us to use the term `global` so i have to use something other than `global`.
For example:

```
    a = 100
    def withdraw():
         global a
         ko = input("Please enter the amount you want to withdraw:")
         if ko > a:
             print "You don't have " + " " + str(ko) + " " + "in your account."
             print "Going back to main menu..."
         else:
             a = a - ko
             print str(ko) + "Dollar" + "withdrawn from your account"
```

Comment: You don't even need classes here. You could just pass `a` into the function, then return the new value of `a`.

Comment: I would bet your teacher has a specific method they prefer and we can't know which that is: the best option would be to seek clarification.

Comment: I know classes the term but the professor also not allow to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular example, I'd simply pass `a` in, and return it back to the caller:

```
# Renamed a to balance
def withdraw(balance):
    # Take input as before

    return balance - ko

a = 100
a = withdraw(a)
```

Whenever possible, pass any relevant data in, and return any results back.

Comment: I tried to use this solution but i saw that error ; TypeError: withdraw(balance) takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: @EnesUzun Note how I used `withdraw` at the bottom of the code. I'm passing `a` in. You missed that part.

Comment: The balance system is working but i have a couple of questions. When i wrote return balance - ko , i can't code anything under the  "return" line, i have to go back to main menu. Last problem is, when i used withdraw function and go back to main menu and call deposit function and print balance, the result going to be "100" as we write at the beginning. "Balance" the value is not changing.

Comment: @EnesUzun For the first question, functions end when `return` is run. The function exits when it gets to a `return`. For the second question, again, note how I wrote the code. You need to reassign `a`. I wrote that code a specific way for a reason. Based on your questions, you need to review how `return` works. It's an incredibly important topic, so be sure to review it more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the **global variable** (we are going to use `account` instead of `a` for this example) a **local variable** in your main and use it in every function that requires it. In this case something like this:

```
def withdraw(account):
    # ... code here
    account -= ko
    print str(ko) + " Dollar withdrawn from your account"
    return account
```

and you would call it like this

```
account = withdraw(account)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can avoid using global variables in your code for e.g. by using instance variables.

As your teacher suggests, you should avoid global variables because you may mistakenly declare another variable with the same name and then while reading the code, it will not be obvious which variable is getting accessed, making it hard to debug your code.

I suggest something similar to this:

```
class BankAccount():

    def __init__(self, initial_balance):
        self.balance = initial_balance

    def withdraw(self, withdraw_amount=0):
        if withdraw_amount > self.balance:
            print "You don't have " + " " + str(withdraw_amount) + " " + "in your account."
            print "Going back to main menu..."
        else:
            self.balance -= withdraw_amount
            print str(withdraw_amount) + "Dollar" + "withdrawn from your account"
```

Following this you can create an instance of a bank account and withdraw form it in the following way:

```
bank_account = BankAccount(initial_balance=1000)
bank_account.withdraw(withdraw_amount=100)
```